# How to write a RuboCop Cop to prevent writing Sidekiq workers using keyword arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, rubocop

Not too long ago, I've found out that [you can't use keyword arguments when defining Sidekiq workers](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2372). Since it only raises an exception after it gets enqueued, I want to prevent this from reaching production for good. And for that, I'd like to add a cop that checks the arguments for `#perform` and raises an error if there's a keyword argument being used. This is my failed attempt so far:

```rb
module RuboCop
  module Cop
    class SidekiqDontUseKeywordArguments < RuboCop::Cop::Cop
      MSG = "Don't use keyword arguments in workers".freeze
      OBSERVED_METHOD = :perform

      def on_def(node)
        return if node.method_name != OBSERVED_METHOD

        node.arguments.each do |argument|
          if keyword_argument?(argument)
            add_offense(node, location: :expression)
          end
        end
      end

      private

      def keyword_argument?(argument)
        # detect if the argument is a keyword
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm missing two things here. The first and most important is that I don't know how to tell whether an argument is a keyword or not. The second is that I'd like to apply this cop only for Sidekiq workers. Am I following the right approach here? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable specific cops for only your Sidekiq workers by using [inheritance](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/#inheritance). For example, if your workers live in `app/workers` then you can create a new ruleset there that inherits from your project’s root and then enables your custom cop:

```
# app/workers/.rubocop.yml
inherit_from:
  - ../../.rubocop.yml
require:
  - ../lib/rubocop/cop/custom/sidekiq_dont_use_keyword_arguments.rb
Custom/SidekiqDontUseKeywordArguments:
  Enabled: true
# For validation of this theory only; do not use this
Lint/DuplicateMethods:
  Enabled: false
```

To make your custom cop detect keyword arguments use the `node.type` method. The elements of `node.arguments` are themselves nodes and support the same methods, and reading the `type` of an argument will return one of four values:

```
# Standard argument: perform(foo)
:arg

# Optional standard argument: perform(foo = 1)
:optarg

# Keyword argument: perform(foo:)
:kwarg

# Optional keyword argument: perform(foo: 1)
:kwoptarg
```

So check for `:kwarg` and `:kwoptarg` (and note the path change and additional `Custom` module to define this cop's department):

```
# app/lib/rubocop/cop/custom/sidekiq_dont_use_keyword_arguments.rb

module RuboCop
  module Cop
    module Custom
      class SidekiqDontUseKeywordArguments < RuboCop::Cop::Cop
        MSG = "Don't use keyword arguments in workers".freeze
        OBSERVED_METHOD = :perform

        def on_def(node)
          return if node.method_name != OBSERVED_METHOD

          node.arguments.each do |argument|
            if argument.type == :kwarg || argument.type == :kwoptarg
              add_offense(node, location: :expression)
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Let’s use this as an example worker:

```
# app/workers/example_worker.rb
class ExampleWorker
  # Standard argument; this will not trigger the cop
  def perform(foo); end

  # Optional standard argument; this will not trigger the cop
  def perform(foo = 1); end

  # Keyword argument; this will trigger the cop
  def perform(foo:); end

  # Optional keyword argument; this will trigger the cop
  def perform(foo: 1); end
end
```

Running Rubocop will return the following output:

```
rubocop app/workers
Inspecting 1 file
C

Offenses:

app/workers/example_worker.rb:9:3: C: Custom/SidekiqDontUseKeywordArguments: Don't use keyword arguments in workers
  def perform(foo:); end
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
app/workers/example_worker.rb:12:3: C: Custom/SidekiqDontUseKeywordArguments: Don't use keyword arguments in workers
  def perform(foo: 1); end
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

1 file inspected, 2 offenses detected
```